# What is the Runway Design Code (RDC) for San Francisco airport (KSFO)?

Tags: airport, runways, datasets

I need the Runway Design Code (RDC) for the SFO airport. Can anyone provide a link for this and possibly other airports? I have checked the SFO Master Plan/Development Plan and found nothing.

Comment: **Why do you need it?** I suspect that you're looking for some fact that you believe will be in it. As a general rule, then, ask about that fact rather than asking for where to find a specified resource, whether or not that resource might provide the fact sought. That way the question (and its answer(s)) will remain useful even after the specific resource sought becomes unavailable, should that happen.

Comment: Why can't I ever get a straight answer on this sight?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm not sure what you meant by "in it", but the RDC isn't a code in the sense of "a collection of rules and guidelines"; it's a single value per runway that tells you what type of aircraft and operations it was designed to handle. This question is like asking for the runway length, surface or some other specific characteristic. At least, that's my understanding after quickly searching; I'd never heard of the RDC before.

Comment: https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/draft_150_5300_13a.pdf#page271

Comment: @P-dub [the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) has been the cause of a lot of wasted time on SE sites, whose communities are kept alive by volunteers. Please don't be disrespectful when community members ask for clarifications about your question.

Answer (score 2):

D-VI. No link. A380 requires this and operates there, so that is minimum. 
E is military, VI is a high as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some folks use ARC (which should be for the entire airport, not just for one runway) when they really mean RDC.  This is a 2011 doc for SFO (which confirms the D-VI code).  Codes are on page 7.

[San Francisco International Airport
Runway Safety Area Program](http://sfmea.sfplanning.org/2010.0755E_FMND.pdf)